# How do you search an Odoo Object knowing its id?

Tags: java, odoo-12

Odoo : the following code returns a Array of 'java.lang.Integer' ids.

```
asList((Object[])models.execute("execute_kw", asList(
db, uid, password,
"res.partner", "search",
asList(asList(
    asList("is_company", "=", true),
    asList("customer", "=", true))))));

[7, 18, 12, 14, 17, 19, 8, 31, 26, 16, 13, 20, 30, 22, 29, 15, 23, 28, 74]
```

Which reverse call will return the structure and values of each Object associated to each ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the read command.

```
final List ids = asList((Object[])models.execute(
            "execute_kw", asList(
            db, uid, password,
            "res.partner", "search",
            asList(asList(
                asList("is_company", "=", true),
                asList("customer", "=", true))))));

final Map record = (Map)((Object[])models.execute(
    "execute_kw", asList(
        db, uid, password,
        "res.partner", "read",
        asList(ids)
    )
))[0];
```

work through those examples:

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/webservices/odoo.html